# Deploy SignalR on small Intranet without using Windows Server

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, signalr

I have an ASP-based application which provides real-time data from a local server to a small group of local users via mobile and desktop browsers (around 10 at any one time). Most of my installations use IIS running on Windows 7 Pro. Until now I have been using ajax short polling but am now prototyping changing the transport to SignalR.

Unfortunately it seems that using IIS on Windows 7 is not an option with since SignalR keeps a large number of connections open and in this configuration IIS has a concurrent connection limit of 10:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms

I am considering attempting to use IIS Express for my deployments. Is this a route worth pursuing? What are the pitfalls? Do I have any other options (other than to install Windows Server).

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use self host signalR on a windows service see [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host) for a sample

I use it on a Win7 machine